# Change drawing coordinates to Printer

Tags: vb.net, printing, coordinates

Hope someone can help?

I have code that outputs a graph to a PictureBox by drawing to its Graphics; which works well.

I now need to print this, but am struggling how to convert the sizes used to support printing (by default it all comes out too small).

If, for example, I draw a box 200x200 on the Picturebox, how would I convert this 200 x 200 so that an equivalent sized box is printed (using 300 printer resolution)?   I am hoping there is an easy way to create a function that can return the adjusted 200 (or whatever size is passed in).

Thanks in advance

Phil

Comment: see bitmap class and its resolution para

Comment: I have set the bitmap to a 300 resolution using SetResolution (to get the quality of printout), but it is this change that causes the grief.  What I need to understand is how to change the original 200x200 to a new size based on now using a 300 resolution?   Thanks